# how to deal with Long URL in LaTeX

Tags: line-breaking, urls

I am a green hand in LaTeX. I sought online and found a lot of posts about the question I asked. However, I cannot follow their instructions. Could anyone give me a hand ?  (OS is ubuntu 12.04.)

The example code are as follows:

```
\url{http://www.coreavc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1}
```

what is the LaTeX code which can wrap this long URL?

The latex code I have is: 
[image]
[image]

The result is like this. For URLs, they do not wrap automatically but go out of the page. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! [Seems to work fine as-is for me.](https://gist.github.com/8391860) http://i.stack.imgur.com/qMhKG.png Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! There are quite a few postings on this site about typesetting long URL strings. (E.g., go to the tags page and search for the `url` tag.) Please consider posting an MWE (minimum [non]working example of what you've tried doing so far.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have solved it. The system I used is Ubuntu 12.04. I have added some figures for my problem. To solve it, we need to add one package: \usepackage{breakurl}

Comment: Adding a minimal working example does not mean adding an image with some code in it! You should have make a copy of this code and edit this into your question.

Comment: failure to break urls in a hyperref document is a common problem if you're using the latex→dvips→pstopdf route.  i believe that, if you use pdflatex, the problem won't arise.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach: Split the linked URL and the link text with `\href`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

Only Domain:
\href{http://www.coreavc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1}{http://www.coreavc.com}

Domain with description:
\href{http://www.coreavc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1}{http://www.coreavc.com Subpage I want}

Domain with description:
\href{http://www.coreavc.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=27&Itemid=1}{http://www.coreavc.com Start $\to$ Menu 1 $\to$ Menu2}

\end{document}
```

[image: Text with marked links]

Remark for the 3rd version (navigation path): There you can describe how you can find the page via web navigation (or menu pathes). This may also help a reader, if the link will break in future - unless the webpage is reorganized completely.

There are also packages to print menus, e.g. [menukeys](http://ctan.org/pkg/menukeys)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once and I managed to get a solution I could live with by using the command \sloppy

\sloppy allows Latex for a more flexible handling of line breaks. The command \fussy turns the standard behaviour back on.

So, my solution looked like that

```
% parts of the document
\sloppy

% the paragraph containing the very long URL

\fussy
% the rest of the document
```

Comment: `\begin{sloppypar} ... \end{sloppypar}` has the same effect as `\sloppy ... \fussy` and perhaps more clearly indicates that there's an intended and defined scope.

Comment: Your are definitely right. This gives the source code more structure.

Answer (score -1):

another point of view, use a shorter url --- https://bitly.com/ --- which looks better and it forwards an interested user towards your long url. concerning your content, it is clear that you are writing about eclipse within the footnote(s). hence, no need that a long eclipse url is stated within the footnote(s).

Comment: But these links don't always last very long and are out of your control.

Comment: till now, had never a prob with bitmarks. when registering, you have an overview about your links (for instance, clicks). obviously, i cannot guarantee that every bitmark exists forever. (maybe they have implemented a deletion strategy for unused links)

Comment: Fair enough, I read your answer as a general one about url shorteners rather than a specific recommendation, and I've has issues with others in the past.

Comment: Even with such a shortened URL the issue of the OP can appear, when the URL is at the very end of a line, so you do not provide a true solution. Apart from this: URL shorteners hide the real source, what I strongly dislike.